# REST API Response.ok(entity).build() doesn't show text

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, intellij-idea, tostring

I am creating a simple Restful API for a school exercise but I'm running into a problem. When I try to show a list of entities, or just a single entity on the webpage it doesn't show any text. It does seem to find the right entities (when I filter, it shows the correct number of entities), it just doesn't show the text. Maybe it doesn't run the ToString? But I don't see anything wrong in my ToString method.

Here's an example:

Function to return a user in my UserResources:

```
@GET //GET at http://localhost:XXXX/users/1
    @Path("{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getUserPath(@PathParam("id") int Id) {
        User user = fakeDatabase.getUser(Id);
        if (user == null) {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity("Please provide a valid user ID.").build();
        } else {
            return Response.ok(user).build();
        }
    }
```

getUser in FakeDatabase:

```
public User getUser(int userId) {
        for (User user : userList) {
            if (user.GetUserId() == userId) {
                return user;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

User ToString:

```
@Override
    public String toString() {
        String WishlistItems = "";
        for(String item : Wishlist){
            WishlistItems = WishlistItems + item + ", ";
        }

        return "User (" + UserId + ") {" + "\n" +
                "Email Address = " + EmailAddress + "\n" +
                "UserName = " + UserName + "\n" +
                Platform.toString() + " ID = " + PlatformID + "\n" +
                "Wishlist :" + WishlistItems + "\n" +
                "}" + "\n";
    }
```

The result I get on the website:

[image]

Anyone know a solution to this problem?

EDIT: The full user class (also I updated the toString method):

```
@XmlRootElement
public class User {
    private int UserId;
    private String UserName;
    private String EmailAddress;
    private int PasswordHash;
    private Platform Platform;
    private String PlatformID;
    private ArrayList<String> Wishlist = new ArrayList<String>();

    public User(int userId, String Password, String emailAddress, String userName, Platform platform, String platformID){
        UserId = userId;
        EmailAddress = emailAddress;
        UserName = userName;
        Platform = platform;
        PlatformID = platformID;
        hashPassword(Password);
    }

    public User(){

    }

    public int GetUserId(){
        return UserId;
    }

    public String GetUserName(){
        return UserName;
    }

    public void SetUserName(String UserName){
        this.UserName = UserName;
    }

    public String GetEmailAddress(){
        return EmailAddress;
    }

    public void SetEmailAddress(String EmailAddress){
        this.EmailAddress = EmailAddress;
    }

    public Platform GetPlatform(){
        return Platform;
    }

    public void SetPlatform(Platform Platform){
        this.Platform = Platform;
    }

    public String GetPlatformID(){
        return PlatformID;
    }

    public void SetPlatformID(String PlatformID){
        this.PlatformID = PlatformID;
    }

    public void AddToWishlist(String item){
        Wishlist.add(item);
    }

    public ArrayList<String> GetWishlist(){
        return Wishlist;
    }

    public void SetWishlist(ArrayList<String> Wishlist){
        this.Wishlist = Wishlist;
    }

    public void hashPassword(String Password) {
        PasswordHash = Objects.hash(Password);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        User user = (User) o;
        return UserId == user.GetUserId();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String WishlistItems = "";
        for(String item : Wishlist){
            WishlistItems = WishlistItems + item + ", ";
        }

        return "User (" + UserId + ") {" + "\n" +
                "Email Address = " + EmailAddress + "\n" +
                "UserName = " + UserName + "\n" +
                Platform.toString() + " ID = " + PlatformID + "\n" +
                "Wishlist :" + WishlistItems + "\n" +
                "}" + "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you paste User class here as well?

Comment: The problem seems to be with your getter setter methods. All the standard libraries follow camelCase. Since your getter and setter starts with capital letters, jackson is not able to serialize these. Use method names like getUserId, getUserName, setUserId etc.

Comment: @Akash WOW! I would have never came up with changing the casing, I didn't know it so heavily relied on it... Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response entity is not serialized via the `toString()` mehtod. If you want to return a string then you have to set a string entity by calling `user.toString()` yourself.
If you set an object as entity it will be treated as an POJO. This means you have to define appropriate setXXX/getXXX methods for your attributes. Your `User` class uses the wrong case.

Have a look at [Set a Response Body in JAX-RS](https://www.baeldung.com/jax-rs-response) for more details (Especially section 3.4. JSON Response Using POJO may be in your interest)

Comment: Thanks! Would have never came up with that it could have relied on camelCasing / PascalCasing...

Answer (score 0):

You tagged your question with Spring Boot, but Spring Boot code does look different. Try it with something like that:

```
@GetMapping("/users/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<User> getUserPath(@PathVariable("id") int Id) {
    User user = fakeDatabase.getUser(Id);
    if (user == null) {
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Please provide a valid user ID.");
    } else {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(user);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an purpose :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {
    @GET //GET at http://localhost:XXXX/users/1
    @Path("/{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public Response<User> getUserPath(@PathParam("id") int Id) {
       return fakeDatabase.getUser(Id).ifPresentOrElse(u -> Response.ok(u), return Response.empty());
    }
}

public class FakeBase {
    public Optional<User> getUser(int userId) {
        return userList.stream().filter(u -> u.hasId(userId)).findFirst();
    }
}

public class User () {
    public boolean hasId(int id) {
        return this.id == id; 
    }
}
```

`User.toString()` is useless.